How to copy text to clipboard from status bar (statusline) in Vim
Problem is present when there is the following option for mouse in ~./vimrc:
set mouse=a | " active


You can't copy because set mouse=a gives Vim full control of the mouse.
Since this is vi.stackexchange.com, a proper Vim solution would simply be to:

disable mouse handling with :set mouse=,
select whatever you want with the mouse and copy it,
re-enable mouse handling with :set mouse=a.


Why not to just use Shift + mouse selection?

Because Shift + mouse selection is system/terminal-specific.

Hold Shift, then copy like in terminal (select text with mouse, press Ctrl + Shit + C)
Related question:

linux - How do I copy command output in vim? - Super User


this works only in a terminal

@ChristianBrabandt In the GUI you can hold Ctrl+Shift while selecting text with the mouse. If 'guioptions' contains a the selection is automatically put into the selection register "* on X11 systems; on Windows the clipboard is used. (See :help modeless-selection.)

Oh, this works always in all GUIs? I have learned something :) Thanks @JürgenKrämer
